# После сборки в .jar перестал работать метод класса

Tags: javafx, maven, jar

Всем привет! Помогите с решением одной проблемы.
Делаю небольшую программку по считыванию и обработке файлов .csv в IntelliJ Idea. Проект JavaFX в Maven. В среде все работает корректно. 
В классе CsvHandler вызывается метод readFileCsv класса CsvReader.

```
public class CsvHandler {
public static void handler()  {

        String sopFilePath = "C:\\Users\\dmitry.fayzulin\\Desktop\\sop.csv";
        MainController.generateAlert(sopFilePath);
        List<String[]> arraySop = CsvReader.readFileCsv(sopFilePath);
        ...
        }
}
```

метод generateAlert() выбрасывает окно с переданной ему строкой и в коде выше, работает беспрекословно.

А вот класс:

```
package mavenjavafxapp.csvHandler;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import mavenjavafxapp.controller.MainController;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvReader {
    public static List<String[]> readFileCsv(String filePath){
        MainController.generateAlert("CsvReader");
        List<String[]> myEntries = null;
        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "cp1251"),
                ';', '\'', 1);
            myEntries = reader.readAll();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            MainController.generateAlert("ошибка"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return myEntries;
    }
}
```

Тут уже MainController.generateAlert() не отрабатывает, ну и дальше собственно программа не идет.

файл pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.javafx</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
                    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>mavenjavafxapp.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven JAR Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>mavenjavafxapp.MainApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

P.S. Я так понял, загвоздка в библиотеке au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader, если закомментировать ее и строки, использующие данную библиотеку, программа продолжает работать.

Comment: Есть ли ошибки? Исключения?

Comment: нет, ошибки и исключения не появляются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избавился от библиотеки, считал файл другим способом:

```
public class Reader extends ArrayList<String[]>{
public Reader (String fileName){
    //String fileName = "C:\\Users\\dmitry.fayzulin\\Desktop\\sop.csv";
    String line;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "cp1251"));
        br.readLine();
        while (( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] row = line.split(";");
            this.add(row);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}